# Strange $zend_framework codes in files (Wordpress, SMF)

Tags: wordpress, zend-framework, frameworks, smf

About a week ago, I found some strange code in all of my wordpress and SMF sites' files. The code is in every file which uses Wordpress' or SMF's API, even if it's not a default file of the specified system. It's starting with a $zend_framework variable, and if I uncode it with unphp.net, I get an obfuscated strange PHP class.

I contacted my host, if it's a 'normal' error of the zend framework, but they said no, it's some weird code.

I searched for some answer in Google and I found some articles that says that there's some hackers may use this way to hack a Wordpress website, but I did not found any sign of unwished logins to my website, but sometimes it does some weird things, for example, one of my API  (which uses Wordpress' API) stopped working perfectly about the time when this code appeared in the files. It's worked before, but after it, for example, instead of the 'Bad request' message it's returned a 'A@' message.

What is this code? It's a bug of the zend framework, or somebody is trying to hack my website?

Here is the code decoded with UnPHP:
http://www.unphp.net/decode/c0958d9db747d5a32c8308ba2fcf4d27/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone isn't *trying* to hack your website, they've succeeded. This is a well known Wordpress exploit. It has nothing to do with Zend Framework (which Wordpress doesn't use). You need to restore your site from a safe backup, or start from a clean Wordpress install.

More info here: http://www.justbeck.com/zend_framework-wordpress-hacks/

Comment: Thanks for your information, but I have some quiestions. First of all, I readed this article before, but I did not found any URL request in the decoded code. What can the code do in my case? And how can I protect my website against this attacks?

Comment: The code has been encoded multiple times. You'll see that the decoded output you linked contains encoded data - this would need decoding as well. I remember trying to decode this once and getting bored after about the 5th level of encoding. To protect your site you need to ensure you always keep your Wordpress installation patched and up date.